# Checking the result of symbolic integro-differentiation

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, differentials

There is an expression:

```
eqn = x'[t] - J y'[t]
```

I first find the integral and then differentiate with respect to $x(t)$ or $y(t)$

```
ieqn = Integrate[eqn, t]

D[ieqn, x[t]]

Out[85]= 1

D[ieqn, y[t]]

Out[86]= -J
```

I get correct results. Now let's write:

```
eqn = x'[t] - J[t] y'[t]
```

Here we need to apply integration by parts. https://www.mathcentre.ac.uk/resources/uploaded/mc-ty-parts-2009-1.pdf

```
ieqn = Integrate[x'[t], t] - (J[t] Integrate[y'[t], t] - Integrate[D[J[t], t] Integrate[y'[t], t], t])
```

Again, the results of differentiation with respect to to $x(t)$ or $y(t)$:

```
D[ieqn, x[t]]

Out[89]= 1

D[ieqn, y[t]]

Out[90]= 0
```

Why did I get the result $0$ when differentiating with respect to $y(t)$? Does the Mathematica give the correct result or is it an error?

Comment: @Nasser I'm sorry, this is a typo. I fixed it. Of course it's about $x(t)$ and $y(t)$, not $x'(t)$ and not $y'(t)$

Answer (score 1):

The result is correct, according to Mathematica's calculus. You have this result

```
ieqn = Integrate[x'[t], t] - (J[t] Integrate[y'[t], t] - Integrate[D[J[t], t] Integrate[y'[t], t], t])
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now you want to differentiate the above w.r.t `y[t]` and you were asking why you got zero.

Well, there are two parts in the above that has `y[t]` in them. Lets do them one at a time.

```
D[-J[t] y[t], y[t]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now lets do the second one

```
D[ Integrate[y[t]*J'[t], t],   y[t]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If you now add the above two results, you do get zero which is what Mathematica gave.

The critical part is that `D[ Integrate[y[t]*J'[t], t],   y[t]] = J[t]` according to Mathematica's calculus.  Here is the proof

$$
I=\frac{d}{dy\left(  t\right)  }\int\left(  y\left(  t\right)  \frac{dJ}
{dt}\right)  dt
$$

Assuming we can move the derivative inside the integration (i.e. integrand is continuous and have partial derivatives)  the above becomes

$$
I=\int\frac{d}{dy\left(  t\right)  }\left(  y\left(  t\right)  \frac{dJ}
{dt}\right)  dt
$$

Applying the product rule gives

\begin{align*}
I  & =\int\left(  \frac{dy\left(  t\right)  }{dy\left(  t\right)  }\frac
{dJ}{dt}+y\left(  t\right)  \frac{d}{dy\left(  t\right)  }\left(  \frac
{dJ}{dt}\right)  \right)  dt\\
& =\int\left(  1\times\frac{dJ}{dt}+y\left(  t\right)  \times0\right)  dt\\
& =\int\frac{dJ}{dt}dt\\
& =\int dJ\\
& =J
\end{align*}

I myself find it strange to differentiate `y[t]` w.r.t. `y[t]` and get `1` since one normally differentiates w.r.t to a variable, and `y[t]` is not a variable, but a function.  Maple does not do it for example:

```
restart;
diff( y(t), y(t))
Error, invalid input: diff received y(t), which is not valid for its 2nd argument
```

But in Mathematica

```
D[y[t], y[t]]
(*  1  *)
```

Comment: It is very strange. The original function depends on the parameter $y(t)$. And the result says that regardless of the change in $y(t)$, the function does not change ... Suppose the second result can be approximated by a function $x(t)-B(t)*y(t)$. This means that the results should be similar, that is $1$ and $B(x)$. Regarding differentiations with respect to a parameter, this is often found in the calculus of variations.

Comment: @dtn yes, in variation of calculus, but that is called $\delta(f(t))$, not in single variable calculus. Anyway, Using your result, Mathematica's result of zero is correct. Added little math showing it is correct.